# Tab buttons similar to iPhone

Tags: android, button, tabs

I was just wondering if anyone knew of an open-source custom view or even a way to make a decent strip of buttons on Android similar to the image below

[image: Nice tab strip]

I have looked at the tab views and such Android provides and it isn't what the client is looking for in terms of aesthetics. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should implement a custom `RadioGroup` to implement the `UISegmentedControl` you have shown in the image.  see this github project which implements just that!

https://github.com/makeramen/android-segmentedradiobutton

Here is another resource i've used to implement the same thing you're after:
http://blog.bookworm.at/2010/10/segmented-controls-in-android.html